# Emitting event from child to parent component not working in Vue.js (using class-based decorator)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am quite new to Vue.js, and for some reason the child to parent emit is not working.

Basically, I have `Search` component within a `Box` component. On my `Search` component, I tried doing:

```
@Watch("searchValue", { immediate: true })
onSearch(value: string, oldValue: string) {
    console.log(this.searchValue); // this is logged OK
    this.$emit("search-val-change", this.searchValue);
}
```

Then on the box component template:

```
<box @search-val-change="doSearch">
    <search></search>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</box>
```

On the box.ts file:

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Box extends Vue {
    doSearch() {
        console.log("TEST EMIT"); // nothing is console logged, means it doesn't come to this part at all
    }    
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "doSearch" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

...although it is defined as a method. I am using the Vue Class Decorator which states that I can define methods directly.

Anything wrong with the syntax / flow?

Comment: change your this.$emit("search-val-change", this.searchValue); to this.$emit("searchValChange", this.searchValue);  i am solution

Comment: Is the `box.ts` file the same location of the `<box @search-val-change="doSearch">
` bit of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emitted string `@search-val-change` is on the box component instead of the `search` child component

It should be something like this

#### box.vue

```html
<SearchComponent @search-val-change="doSearch">
...
</SearchComponent>
```

Also, don't forget to register your search component in the `box.vue` file. It should be something like this

```js
@Component({
    components: {
        SearchComponent
    },
})
export default class Box extends Vue {
    doSearch() {
        console.log("TEST EMIT");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I misunderstood. So basically the child receives the method from parent instead of the parent receiving the child event.

Comment: Exactly! In the child component, the emission takes place, and in the parent component, the emitted string is “watched“ by the child component, which triggers the doSearch method (in your case) in the parent component.

Comment: @catandmouse, you can see more about this [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events).

Answer (score -1):

Custom methods should be in `methods`, like so:

```
@Component
export default class Box extends Vue {
  methods: {
    doSearch() {
      console.log("TEST EMIT"); // nothing is console logged, means it doesn't come to this part at all
    }
  }
}
```